# php streaming video : can tmp file be accessed before move_uploaded_file?

Tags: php, file, file-upload, ffmpeg, video-streaming

My question is about accessing file while they are being uploaded to the server.

Can I perform "live" video streaming but BEFORE move_uploaded_file ???

because move_uploaded_file have to wait until the video is completely finished.

```
<?php
// Can I access tmp before move_uploaded_file ?
move_uploaded_file('tmp_name','new_location');
```

Is there a way to access the tmp file during upload and perform ffmpeg ?

I was considering upload by chunk via xhr request... but it seems .mp4 from a mobile don't necessarily apply a fast start...

how live streaming services companies do it ?

---

**** More clarifications:
Live streaming. Example User X take his phone and want to go live, he hit a button "stream yourself" than the camera starts recording and while uploading, the server begins to save it to the server and other users like Y, Z, A, B begin to watch while X is still begin live

Comment: if you want to edit your question. Edit your question. Please don't use the comments to ask more questions.

Comment: It totally depends on the file format. A transport stream for example will work like that. An MP4 on the other had can only do that if fast start was applied.

Comment: @szatmary ok, good to know. but how video streaming services does it ?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to create a live stream from a camera or other source? Or are you trying to take a recorded video and optimize how long it takes to be available after upload?  Because I suspect this is an [X Y problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: @szatmary Live streaming. Example User X take his phone and want to go live, he hit a button "stream yourself" than the camera starts recording and while uploading, the server begins to save it to the server and other users like Y, Z, A, B begin to watch while X is still begin live

Comment: Rite, So uploading an mp4 will never work for this scenario. So the question is totally invalid. Streaming services use ingest protocols like RTMP, or alternatives such as SRT, or the DASH ingest purpose.

Comment: @szatmary thanks for the RTMP, SRT and DASH terms, at least I can search this.

Comment: I found 2 interesting WebRTC server open source https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway •• and •• https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Comment: and maybe also https://github.com/ant-media/Ant-Media-Server/